# Recalling the latest date on views.py

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to receive the latest date from a Queryset.

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
stock = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
min_stock = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Meta:
    get_latest_by = 'date_created'


def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name
```

So that I can display on my html, the latest dates of when each customer has made an order and updates itself as each time a order has been made.

However when I try this queryset,

`latest_order = Order.objects.order_by('date_created').last()`

I receive the name of the product rather than the date_created, is there a way of receiving the latest date_created per customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

latest_order_per_user = Order.objects.annotate(
    latest=Max('user__order__date_created')
).filter(date_created=F('latest'))
```

If you want to get just dates you can use *[values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)* method:

```
latest_order_per_user = Order.objects.annotate(
        latest=Max('user__order__date_created')
    ).filter(date_created=F('latest'))
latest_dates = last_order_per_user.values('date_created')
```

Comment: No luck  just received this , which are the names of the products as a list <QuerySet [<Order: Dumb Bells>, <Order: Dumb Bells>, <Order: Dishes>, <Order: Tie>, <Order: Mouse>, <Order: Headband>]>

Comment: @kamcoder my last update should give the last order date per user

Comment: It gave me the list of all dates, however i added .last() in the end of the query. However i would need last date for each user.

Answer (score 0):

this is work,as you see i put a dash inside a bracket

```
latest_order = Order.objects.order_by('-date_created')
```